# C++ Netbeans No output for very simple program

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am working on a program for a class.  Yesterday my progress so far was working.
Today my output shows nothing.  I've been working at trying to find the problem - and concluded that something must have happened in NetBeans.  Below is a program that I made just to test this - this is not my class project (I wish it were this simple).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout<<"anything"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if I go to run>test project I receive the following output:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cplustribulation.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
make[2]: 'dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cplustribulation.exe' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-tests-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '.build-tests-conf'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Pietzyk/Desktop/School/CSCI455/labs/NumsTester/cPlusTribulation'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:67: recipe for target '.build-tests-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-tests-impl] Error 2

BUILD TESTS FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I do not know what any of this means.  Although I'm assuming that the line with "*** No rule to make target"  must be some sort of indicator as to my issue.  I receive the same message with my class project.

When ran my output is:

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 79ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I go to run>test project

Test  project requires you to actually have tests. You don't so that why your build is failing.

You should use Run / Run project or Build Project.

Or find this button [image: Run button].

As for the output: You have under Project properties (Right click project name). Choose the Run category. Here you have several options, Console type, where to direct cout.

Comment: Run project provides blank output (other than run successful).  Build output states Build Successful.

Comment: Which is not what I expect.  I expect it to output: anything

Comment: thanks!  Your idea wasn't the issue I was having - but helped me find where the problem was (no idea how it was changed in the course of a save and sleeping then reopening... but who knows.  I'll be making a post as to the issue and very simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

As with most of my programming woes - such a simple fix:

Somewhere I must have fat-fingered something to where in the run>set main project I had changed what my main was.

Thanks Captain Giraffe for helping me trouble-shoot and get down to this problem.